# Swift Generic func calling a Generic func

Tags: swift, generics, swift4

I have an interesting compile error when using one generic to call another. This post is a bit long but hopefully, it's not longer than needed to describe the problem.

I have defined a generic func that works great.  I use it a lot and the pattern of use is often the same.  I was trying to implement a new generic func that nests the existing generic func, but I'm getting a compile-time error.

For some context, here is how my API works with the generic now.  My REST API makes a call the films() func, which hits the StarWarsAPI (swapi.co) and returns a list of all the Star Wars films they have in their database, as follows:

```
StarWarsAPI.shared.films(){ (films, error) in
       for film in films {
                print(film.title)
       }  
 }
```

The films() function calls a generic (restCall()) which works great.  Here is the definition of films():

```
public func films(completion: @escaping (_ films:[Film]?, _ error:StarWarsError?) -> Void) {
    guard StarWarsAPI.isOperational else {
        return completion(nil,StarWarsError.starWarsAPINotOperational)

    }
    restCall(fetchUrl: filmsUrl!, modelType: FilmResult()) { (filmResults, error ) in
        completion(filmResults?.results, error)
    }
}
```

Where the restCall (the generic) is defined as follows: (Note I'm using the  Swift 4 Codable API)

```
public func restCall<T: Codable>(fetchUrl: URL, modelType: T, completion: @escaping (_ modelObject: T?, _ error:StarWarsError?) -> Void){

    var fetchRequest = URLRequest(url: fetchUrl, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10.0)

    fetchRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
    fetchRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields = [
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
    ]

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let fetchDataTask = session.dataTask(with: fetchRequest) { (data, response, error) in

        DispatchQueue.main.async { // return to main thread


            var modelObject:T?
            do {

                let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                modelObject = try jsonDecoder.decode(T.self, from: data)// FIXME: Something about decoding the People object is going wrong.
                return completion(modelObject, nil)

            }catch let error as NSError {
                completion(nil, StarWarsError.decodingModelError(error: error))
            }
        }
    }

    fetchDataTask.resume()
}
```

So the above works great. I use it for rest functions films(), people(), ships(), etc. I use the same pattern for each rest call.  I want to create a generic that I can use instead of explicit films(), people(), etc.

I've been trying to get the following to work with little success:

```
    public func fetchAll<T: Result>(result:T,  completionAll:  @escaping (_ result:T?, _ error:StarWarsError?) -> Void) {

       restCall(fetchUrl: result.urlPath!, modelType: T) { (finalResults, error ) in
          completionAll(finalResults!, error)
       }

    }
```

Where Result type is the base type and is defined as follows:

```
public class Result {
    var urlPath:URL?
}
public class FilmResult: Result, Codable {

    var count:Int?
    var next:String?
    var previous:String?
    var results:[Film]?

}
```

The error I'm getting is shown in the screenshot below - hopefully, it's clear.

[image]

Any help you can provide would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call has to be

```
                       this was T previously  ───┐
restCall(fetchUrl: result.urlPath!, modelType: result) { (finalResults, error ) in
```

Note the `result` instead of `T`.

---

Relatively minimal code to reproduce:

```
public func restCall<T>(fetchUrl: URL, modelType: T, completion: @escaping (_ modelObject: T?, _ error:String?) -> Void) { }

public func fetchAll<T>(result:T,  completionAll:  @escaping (_ result:T?, _ error:String?) -> Void) {

                                                          ┌── should be result   
    restCall(fetchUrl: URL(string: "asdasd")!, modelType: T) { (finalResults, error ) in
        completionAll(finalResults, error)
    }
}
```